# how to unbind cursor adpter with listview in android

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I need to know ,how to unbind cursor adapter with listview.

Continuous updates comes to my table.As cursor Adapter already register its observers .It is  directly reflected to listview which hangs my UI why scrolling.

i need to unbind listview with that of updates coming in db.The view only should unbind but the update must still come db.

I tried to extend cursoradpter overide the registerDataObserver.but it stops update coming in to the db.

Kindly assist how to proceed..

Answer (score 0):

Call `adapter.changeCursor(null);` to unbind